# ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER CONNECTION ERROR ON MACBOOK M1

Tags: sql, database, oracle, macos, apple-m1

I'm a new mac user. I need to download the oracle developer server. When I was on Windows, I faced no problem creating a new database and a connection. But facing "**The network adapter could not establish the connection**" error from MacBook with m1 chip.
Is there anyone who faces the same problem and suggests me a simple solution? I've tried many online solutions which didn't work for me.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "oracle developer server". Oracle database doesn't run natively on a Mac. SQL Developer is not a database - it is a client, and you have to have a database to connect to. As far as I'm aware there isn't an emulator that will let you run Oracle DB on an M1 still, though I haven't looked for a while. So, do you have connection details for a (remote) database that already exists and is up and running?

Comment: yup. I got your point. actually, I don't have Oracle DB. So, I'm installing it using Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the listener to see if it is down:-

```
ps -ef | grep tns
```

If you do not find the output of the listener then you have to start it.

From the [Oracle community:](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2547624)

> If the Oracle clients have been installed with 11.1.2.3 the TNS_ADMIN
> will be point to \user_projects\config\dbclient In that folder there
> should be a tnsnames.ora, if the Oracle DB is on the same machine you
> may want to copy the contents of database tnsnames folder to the
> TNS_ADMIN folder or as suggested change the environment variable.